# "utrum quod celebrem sit documento necne": why documento and not documentum

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification

In Latin translation of the *Analects* (didn't find who are the translator(s)) [we read in Chapter 1, verse 4:](https://www.confucius.org/lunyu/latin/latin_nd0104.htm)

> Cotidie de tribus rebus me examino: utrum ...; utrum....; **utrum quod celebrem sit documento necne.**

The bolded part [should mean](https://www.confucius.org/lunyu/ed0104.htm): "whether or not I practice what is imparted". But I could not decipher this ablative (or even dative) *documento*. it appears to be something like *sit documento* = "according to the example/lesson", but how this ablative is standalone without a verb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a dative of purpose ([A&G 382](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/dative-purpose)). *documento esse* means "to serve as a lesson or example."

Comment: thanks. now the word order makes more sense. I do find this a little different from other translations in meaning, but probably stylistic decision by the translator.